# Make method that returns a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog with specified message?

Tags: java, joptionpane

What I am trying to ask here is this:

I've been typing `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`, etc etc, all the time. So, I thought that I could make a method to make it shorter and easier, in this case named `msgDialog()`.

```
public static String msgDialog(String message){
    return JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
```

Why wouldn't this work? (error: cannot return a void result.)

Comment: Why haven't you read the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) - it would have answered you question, although I'm surprised that the compiler error didn't

Comment: Silly me, I thought it wasn't possible to add arguments in the () portion without returning a variable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JOptionPane#showMessageDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) doesn't return anything. Thus, You can do this instead

```
public static void show(String s){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change method type to void :

```
public static void msgDialog(String message){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
```